# As soon as I make a connection between my code and interface, my tab crashes (iOS SDK 4.2)

Tags: xcode, crash, iphone, uitabview

**Using XCode 4, with the iPhone iOS 4.2**

Hey everyone, I'm using a tabBar interface for my new app that I'm trying to finish. I have declared the UILabels and as soon as I connect them in the interface builder to the actual labels, the whole app will crash upon selection of its tab at runtime, in the simulator and on my iphone.

I'm hoping there's a really simple answer out there, but I really have no idea where to look (I am a novice).

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Post some code. There's lots of ways in ObjC to "declare the UILabels" and most of them lead to crashes.

Comment: please post the error from your console logs.

Comment: I solved the problem, thanks for the replys guys. In my mainview.xib that has the tabbar in it, I had the NIB hooked up with the tabs, but I forgot to change the class from UIViewer to the class of the page.

Answer (score 0):

Usually this happens when you change the name of your variables but didn't update the hooks in IB. An easy fix to this that I usually do is to unhook everything in IB, and then hook them back on again.